# How to pass an argument with spaces in a reg file

Tags: windows-7, spaces, regedit

Could anyone tell me how I should do to pass the argument %1 (in the last line) in the following .reg file with double quotes ("%1").

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\CopyDateTimeSuffix]
@=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\CopyDateTimeSuffix\Command]
@="G:\\PRO\\Gemensam\\Program\\CopyDateTimeSuffix\\CopyDateTimeSuffix.bat %1"
```

The thing is that the argument (which holds a filepath) sometimes contains spaces.

Comment: Insert double quotes with `\"%1\"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps like this

```
@="G:\\PRO\\Gemensam\\Program\\CopyDateTimeSuffix\\CopyDateTimeSuffix.bat \"%1\""
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer may be kind of late but here it is :

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\CopyDateTimeSuffix\Command]
@="G:\PRO\Gemensam\Program\CopyDateTimeSuffix\CopyDateTimeSuffix.bat %1%*

then in CopyDateTimeSuffix.bat :

DoSomething.exe "%*"

Note : For some reason the registry returns blank if you only pass the wildcard %* as argument  (Got stuck on that for some time)